# Only audio audible no video seen while playing media through android media player in react native Native-modules

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-modules

I am trying to use native modules on react native and I want to play a video that has been prepared(mediaplayer.prepare()) in an android native mediaplayer . The mediaplayer is then added to a surface view and the surface view is added to the Adview (seen below). After implementing this I am not able to see the video only audio is audible

**View in App.js**

`<AdView adType = {adFormat} adspotKey = {adspotId} />`

**Code in View Manager**

```
package com.adsandroidreactsdk;
import android.view.View;
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.Map;

public class AdViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<AdViewGroup> {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RCTNativeView";
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adType")
    public void setAdspotKey(AdViewGroup view, @Nullable int adType) {
        view.setAdType(adType);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adspotKey")
    public void setAdspotKey(AdViewGroup view, @Nullable String adspot) {
        view.setAdspotId(adspot);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adHeight")
    public void setHeight(AdViewGroup view, @Nullable int adHeight) {
        view.setHeight(adHeight);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adWidth")
    public void setWidth(AdViewGroup view, @Nullable int adWidth) {
        view.setWidth(adWidth);
    }

    @Override
    protected AdViewGroup createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new AdViewGroup(reactContext);
    }


}
```

**AdViewGroup Class**

```
public class AdViewGroup extends ReactViewGroup implements LifecycleEventListener {

    protected AdViewLayout mAdView;
    private AdView.AD_TYPE mAdType;
    private String mAdspotKey;
    private RCTEventEmitter mEventEmitter;
    int pxW, mWidth;
    int pxH, mHeight;
    FrameLayout mIcon;
    RelativeLayout mMedia;
    ThemedReactContext context;

    public void setAdType(int adType) {
        Log.e("Test", "inside setAdType: " + adType);
        if (adType == 1)
            mAdType = AdView.AD_TYPE.INFEED;
        else if (adType == 2)
            mAdType = AdView.AD_TYPE.CONTENT_STREAM;
        else if (adType == 3)
            mAdType = AdView.AD_TYPE.CUSTOM_NATIVE;
        else if (adType == 4)
            mAdType = AdView.AD_TYPE.INSTREAM_VIDEO;

        if (mAdType != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mAdspotKey))
            createAdViewIfCan();
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        Log.e("Test", "inside setHeight: " + height);
        mHeight = height;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        Log.e("Test", "inside setWidth: " + width);
        mWidth = width;
    }

    public void setAdspotId(String adspotKey) {
        Log.e("Test", "inside setAdspotId: " + adspotKey);
        mAdspotKey = adspotKey;
        if (mAdType != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mAdspotKey))
            createAdViewIfCan();
    }

    private int dp2px(int dp, DisplayMetrics dm) {
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, dm));
    }


    private void createAdViewIfCan() {
        if (mAdView == null && mAdspotKey != null) {
            context = (ThemedReactContext) getContext();
            if (context.hasCurrentActivity()) {
                Ads.getInstance().setLogLevel(Ads.LogLevel.DEBUG);
                mAdView = new AdViewLayout(context.getCurrentActivity(), mAdspotKey, mAdType);
                DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                pxW = dp2px(mWidth, dm);  //Put width of required adView
                pxH = dp2px(mHeight, dm);  //Put height of required adView
                Log.e("Test", "pxW: " + pxW);
                Log.e("Test", "pxH: " + pxH);
                mAdView.measure(pxW, pxH);
                mAdView.layout(0, 0, pxW, pxH);
                removeAllViews();
                addView(mAdView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(pxW, pxH));
                setListenerToAdview(context.getCurrentActivity());

              if (mAdType == AdView.AD_TYPE.CUSTOM_NATIVE) {
                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout._custom_native_layout, null);
                    mIcon = (FrameLayout) container.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("_custom_icon", "id",
                            context.getPackageName()));
                    mMedia = (RelativeLayout) container.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("_custom_media_view", "id",
                            context.getPackageName()));
                    TextView descView = (TextView) container.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("_custom_desc", "id",
                            context.getPackageName()));
                    TextView titleView = (TextView) container.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("_tv_title", "id",
                            context.getPackageName()));
                    LayoutParams params = descView.getLayoutParams();
                    LayoutParams params1 = mIcon.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = dm.widthPixels - params1.width;
                    descView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    titleView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    mAdView.setCustomNativeAdContainer(container);
                    mAdView.setCustomImageSize(320, 180);
                }

                mAdView.cacheAd();
            }
        }
    }


    public AdViewGroup(ThemedReactContext context) {
        super(context);
        context.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
        mEventEmitter = context.getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class);
    }


    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onHostDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.onDestroy();
        }
    }


    public void setListenerToAdview(final Activity activity) {

        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(AdView adview, AdError AdError) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdFailedToLoad callback." + AdError.getErrorDescription());
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + AdError.getErrorDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed(AdView adview, boolean isVideoCompleted) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdClosed callback=> " + "isVideoCompleted: " + isVideoCompleted);
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdPrepared(AdView adView) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdPrepared callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdPrepared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdReceived(AdView AdView) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdReceived callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdReceived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAdView.loadAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdClicked callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdRender(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdRender callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdRender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                measureView(mIcon, 48, 48);
                measureView(mMedia, 320, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdMediaStart(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdMediaStart callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdMediaStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdMediaEnd(AdView adview, long l) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdMediaEnd callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdMediaEnd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdRefresh(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdRefresh callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdRefresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                measureView(mIcon, 48, 48);
                measureView(mMedia, 320, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdMediaExpand(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdMediaExpand callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdMediaExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdMediaCollapse(AdView adview) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdMediaCollapse callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdMediaCollapse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdSkippable(AdView AdView) {
                Log.d("Test", "onAdSkippable callback");
                Toast.makeText(context, "onAdSkippable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void measureView(ViewGroup viewGroup, int width/*in DP*/, int height/*in DP*/) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        View child = null;
        if (viewGroup != null) {
            child = viewGroup.getChildAt(0);
        }
        if (child != null) {
            Log.e("Test", " width: " + dp2px(width, dm));
            Log.e("Test", " height: " + dp2px(height, dm));
            child.measure(dp2px(width, dm), dp2px(height, dm));
            child.layout(0, 0, dp2px(width, dm), dp2px(height, dm));
        }
    }
}
```

**AdViewPackage Class**

```
   class AdViewPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new AdViewManager());
    }
}
```